# Custom error page is not loading in NGINX. Default error page is loaded instead

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I have created two custom error pages in nginx server 404.html and 500.html

I was able to load 404.html file without any issues.
But in the place of 500.html, I am getting the default nginx error page (50x.html).
Both the files are in the same folder. Please see my conf file content below

```
error_page   500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

error_page   404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

````
error_page   500 502 503 504 /500.html;
location = /500.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}
 
error_page   404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    internal;
}```
````